# WPF Change position of controls in a listbox as other controls change size

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a template for a listbox item that currently looks like this:

```
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Grid Background="DarkOrange" MaxWidth="431">
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="431">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec tempus sem. 
                    Nunc lobortis magna sed odio ullamcorper sollicitudin. Etiam porttitor malesuada vestibulum. 
                    Nullam et efficitur nibh, sit amet tristique felis. 
                    Fusce vel accumsan dui. Duis aliquam nulla ac turpis vestibulum rutrum. 
                    Phasellus vitae felis at magna ultricies suscipit lacinia eu ipsum.
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
```

As the length of the text changes, so does the height of the Textblock, and the size of the grid background behind it.

How can I add a MediaElement control underneath the Textblock, so that it (and the background) will move up and down along with the size of the Textblock?

Comment: You can use `StackPanel` and fill this with your elements. This will take care of resizing. Another way is to just extend `Grid`/`ListView` and listen for every size change of it's children and then align them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define Rows for your `Grid`. Define the `Height` of your first row as `Auto` this will adjust the `Height` of the row to the `ActualHeight` of it's content. For the second rows height you can define `*`, which will make it fill the rest of the grid.

```
    <Grid Background="DarkOrange" MaxWidth="431">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height ="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" Width="431">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras nec tempus sem. 
                Nunc lobortis magna sed odio ullamcorper sollicitudin. Etiam porttitor malesuada vestibulum. 
                Nullam et efficitur nibh, sit amet tristique felis. 
                Fusce vel accumsan dui. Duis aliquam nulla ac turpis vestibulum rutrum. 
                Phasellus vitae felis at magna ultricies suscipit lacinia eu ipsum.
    </TextBlock>
    <MediaElement Grid.Row="1"></MediaElement>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working, the MediaElement isn't being shown.

Comment: Ah, my mistake I just needed to give it a width and a height!